# Geometric Median Problem with a twist

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, algorithms, convex-optimization, median

Given two vectors $x, y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and scalar $\alpha$, what is the value of $\alpha$ that minimizes $||\alpha x - y ||_1$? Give an algorithm to find the minimum.

I've tried couple of examples by hand but I am not getting anywhere. Either it's the value of $|\alpha x_i - y_i|$ that dominates the function or the median. Is there a systematic way to get the solution?

Comment: What hand you tried ?  Please show your efforts

Comment: You know I am almost certain this is a duplicate, but I'll be darned if I can find it. (So no I am not criticizing! If I can't find it, I can hardly expect you too, either! But I also think we've provided an answer there, so it would be helpful for you if we could.)

Answer (score 1):

The key to solving this problem is to note that $\|ax-y\|_1$ is a piecewise linear, convex function of $a$. Any piecewise linear convex function that is bounded below is minimized at one of its "kinks" or vertices. If you can identify the locations of those kinks, a simple search will be sufficient.

(It's possible for a piecewise linear convex function to achieve its minimum between two kinks; for example, $f(a)=\max\{|a|-1,0\}$. But note that the two surrounding vertices are *also* minimizers. So the search approach is always valid.)

So where are those kinks? In this case, it is exactly the set of points where $ax_i-y_i$ changes sign:
$$a \in \{ y_i / x_i ~|~ i=1,2,\dots, n,~x_i\neq 0\}.$$
Therefore, the solution is
$$a = y_q / x_q, \quad q = \mathop{\textrm{argmin}}_{i:x_i\neq 0} \sum_j |x_jy_i/x_i - y_j|
.$$
You can exhaustively search all $n$ points if you want, for $O(n^2)$ complexity. or you can sort them and start your search from the median value of $a$. That would still be $O(n^2)$ worst case.

Answer (score 0):

This reduces to a Euclidean geometry problem, by restriction to the subspace spanned by $x$ and $y$.

> given a convex polygon $C$ containing $0$ and a line in the plane, find the smallest $b$ such that $bC$ intersects the line.

There are two cases, where the line does/doesn't intersect $C$, which should be similar to the types you described from examples.  Nonintersecting case is the problem of finding lines of support parallel to the given one.

Comment: The use of the 1-norm complicates matters here. If it were the 2-norm we'd have an analytic result.

Comment: The L^1 problem reduces to a (different) L^2 problem.   It's not the directly analogous problem of shortest distance from a point to a line in the L^2 metric.  (In case your comment was based on the words "Euclidean geometry" in the first line.)

Comment: It's not clear to me what $L^2$ problem it would reduce to. I'm interested to hear your further development.

Comment: The convex polygon C in the answer is the graph of the unit circle in the restriction of the L^1 norm to the plane spanned by $x$ and $y$.  We are looking for the point of smallest L^1 norm on a line in that plane.